# Do lambda expressions have a unique use that cannot be replicated through something else?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning about lambda-expressions today, and so far, I haven't found their unique use. So I'm asking myself if they are more than just a handy little gadget, taken from functional languages.

**What are Lambda-Expressions?**

From what I've read, they can be used to instantiate anonymous classes, pass simple methods and filter elements in collections.
For example:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
   for (int i : list)
      System.out.println(i);
```

...can be written as:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
list.forEach((i) -> {
   System.out.println(i);
});
```

But why should you do that? Every time you write down a lambda-expression, you could just put only the raw expression there!

```
public class Test {
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface BoolOperation {
        boolean execute(boolean param1, boolean param2);
    }

    static void test(BoolOperation op, boolean param1, boolean param2) {
        System.out.println(op.execute(param1, param2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test((x, y) -> x && y, true, false);
        
        test((x, y) -> x || y, false, true);
        
        test((x, y) -> x == y, true, true);
    }
}
```

...does the same as:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(true && false);
        System.out.println(false || true);
        System.out.println(true == true);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
                System.out.println("Running.");
        };
    }   
}
```

... is not that much shorter/readable than:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new ThreadThingy();
    }   
}

class ThreadThingy implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running.");
    }
}
```

I've read the [Oracle-Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), but they are very specific and do not highlight a general use.

Comment: In the examples you show there *isn't* a huge benefit. But that's not what they're for: which would you rather do for something like `someList.map(xxx).filter(xxx)`: write it all out by hand, or pass simple one-liner lambdas to `map` and `filter`? Look in to "functional programming", which lambdas clean up *significantly* in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted, your example with the boolean expression can be easier written directly. But what if you want to create truth tables for different boolean expressions?

```
public class Test {
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface BoolOperation {
        boolean execute(boolean param1, boolean param2);
    }

    static void line(String s, BoolOperation op, boolean b1, boolean b2) {
        System.out.printf("%b %s %b = %b%n", b1, s, b2, op.execute(b1, b2));
    }

    static void table(String s, BoolOperation op) {
        System.out.println("Truth table for "+s);
        line(s, op, false, false);
        line(s, op, false, true);
        line(s, op, true, false);
        line(s, op, true, true);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        table("AND", (x, y) -> x && y);
        table("OR", (x, y) -> x || y);
        table("XNOR", (x, y) -> x == y);
        table("XOR", (x, y) -> x != y);
        table("implies", (x, y) -> !x || y);
    }
}
```

You could still do that using anonymous classes for the various operations, but it would take much more "boilerplate" - code that needs to be written just to satisfy the compiler without adding any value.

For example, you could write the first `table` call like this:

```
    table("AND", new BoolOperation() {
        @Override
        public boolean execute(boolean param1, boolean param2) {
            return param1 && param2;
        }
    });
```

but you can't tell me that this more readable and easier to understand than

```
        table("AND", (x, y) -> x && y);
```

---

For a more "real world" example, one of my projects contains a class `ObjectCsvWriter` that takes a `PrintWriter` and a list of `Column` definitions to export a list of objects into a csv file.

A column definition contains the column name and a `Function<T, X>` for extracting the value for that column from the object for that row, with `X` depending on the column type - for a `StringColumn` the expected function is a `Function<T, String>`, for a `DoubleColumn` the expected function is a `Function<T, Double>`.

The code for exporting then looks something like

```
private void exportXxx(List<ExportableXxx> data) {
    List<Column<ExportableXxx>> columns = Arrays.asList(
        new StringColumn<>("Xxx Id", ExportableXxx::getId),
        new StringColumn<>("Xxx Name", ExportableXxx::getName),
        new DoubleColumn<>("Total YYYY", "%.2f", ExportableXxx::getTotal),
        new DoubleColumn<>("Yyyy Type 1", "%.2f", e -> e.getYyyy(Types.Type1)),
        new DoubleColumn<>("Yyyy Type 2", "%.2f", e -> e.getYyyy(Types.Type2)),
        new DoubleColumn<>("Yyyy Type 3", "%.2f", e -> e.getYyyy(Types.Type3)),
        new DoubleColumn<>("Yyyy Type 4", "%.2f", e -> e.getYyyy(Types.Type4)),
        new DoubleColumn<>("Yyyy Other", "%.2f", ExportableXxx::getYyyOther)
    );
    try (ObjectCsvWriter<ExportableXxx> cw = new ObjectCsvWriter<>(
            new PrintWriter(fileName, Charset.defaultCharset()), columns)) {
        cw.printHeader();
        for (ExportableXxx d: data) {
            cw.printLine(d);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("Cannot write export file", e);
    }
}
```

Can you imagine the effort it would need to create an anonymous class for each of the columns listed? (This example uses not only lambdas for extracting values because sometimes using method references is even easier).

Comment: Thank you for this example! I've tried some stuff but cannot replicate a shorter code without lambdas that doesn't use additional variables/hardcoding.
Does it occur frequently, that you have to use so many different operations in the same context? I think in the past I didn't, and this still feels like a bit of a "nice to know" feature to me.

Comment: @xtay2 i've added an example on how I use lambdas (and method references) in one of my projects.